# Finitely Generated Algebra over Commutative Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

Let $R$ be a commutative noetherian ring, A a finitely generated $R$-algebra (not necessarily commutative). Let $B$ be a subalgebra of the center $Z(A)$. Assume $A$ is finitely generated $B$-module. Can we show $B$ is finitely generated $R$-algebra?

Comment: Can you give some context for the question? Is it pure curiosity or is it motivated by something?

Comment: In the case that $A$ is commutative, I think this reduces to the Artin-Tate lemma. Maybe the argument carries over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  When $A$ is commutative, this is known as the [Artin-Tate lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Tate_lemma), and the same proof works in general.  In detail, let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ generate $A$ as an $R$-algebra and let $y_1,\dots,y_m$ generate $A$ as a $B$-module.  We can then choose scalars $b_{ij},b_{ijk}\in B$ such that $$x_i=\sum_j b_{ij}y_j$$ and $$y_iy_j=\sum_k b_{ijk} y_k.$$  Let $B_0\subseteq B$ be the $R$-subalgebra generated by the $b_{ij}$ and $b_{ijk}$, and note that the equations above imply $A$ is still generated by $y_1,\dots,y_m$ as a $B_0$-module (here we use the fact that $B$ is central in $A$, to write any finite product of the $x_i$ as a $B_0$-linear combination of the $y_j$ using the equations above since we can freely pull out the coefficients).  Moreover, since $B_0$ is a finitely generated  commutative $R$-algebra, it is a Noetherian ring by the Hilbert basis theorem, and hence $B$ is also finitely generated as a $B_0$-module.  Since $B_0$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra, this implies $B$ is also a finitely generated $R$-algebra.

Comment: This argument makes a subtle implicit use of the assumption that $B$ is contained in $A$'s center, beyond that it is commutative; maybe draw this out explicitly?